# How to separate the two projects (Angular & express)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I pulled a [project from github](https://github.com/jakblak/chat_app) and it works fine for me.
However, I want just to know how to separate server side and client side projects (sockets part).

In other way, how can I run the two projects (angular project and express project) into two differents servers (for example angular project on `localhost:8080` and express project on `localhost:3000`).

That's gonna help me also to use this code into ionic framework project :)

Comment: 'angular project' isn't Angular project. It has Node part any way.  You can keep client and server side parts in separate projects or in one. Nobody can decide that for you.

Comment: Yes I know, and I want to separate them. The problem is when I excute the command `http-server -o` to run Angular project, and `node server.js` to run Express project, I got some errors. I think there's something to change in code (or files)... related to `socket.io`

Comment: NB : When I run them in one server using `node server.js` all works fine, but it's not what I want :/

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is. If you have errors, you need to provide all relevant details and also [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The question in its current state cannot get a good answer.

Comment: when I excute `http-server -o` with `<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` I got this error : `GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=La2NzCY 404 (Not Found)` same thing when I  put `<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` (client side runs on port 8081 and server side on port 8080)

Comment: Maybe I can't explain myself well (sorry for that). My problem is I never worked with socket.io in a separate projects, so the SOCKET.IO part causes me trouble.

Comment: What i'm looking for, how to use socket.io in remote (always in this example). what I must change in client side (`socket.Srvc.js` file) to run it successfully :) This is exactly the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

1) in `index.html` I must call the socket.io file on my server :

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

2) in `components/socket.Srvc.js`

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

backend server port : `8080`

Now I can run separately two servers without socket.io errors :)